# Paying Dulles (IAD) toll using coins with a rental car, is it possible?

Tags: usa, car-rentals, tolls

I have rented a car at DCA to be returned at IAD. I knew I would have to pay the Dulles toll to drive to IAD, so I did my research online and I saw there would be cash toll booths where I would be able to pay with coins (quarters and one dollar coins).
I had the money required to pay the toll in quarters and I have tried to pay that way. However, for some reason, the machine refused all of my quarters and remained displaying "Pay $3.25".
I followed the instructions saying I would have to pay the missed toll online or by calling them, so I drove on.

The problem is instead of flagging it as a missed toll, the EZ Pass representative told me it was deducted from the EZ Pass the rental had. I asked if she could void the EZ Pass charge and allow me to pay manually for the missed toll, but she said there was nothing she could do.

Do I have any options to prevent the rental company from charging me a $15.00 administrative fee for the EZ pass per toll? I am trying to contact PlatePass (rental), but I don't have much hope.

The representative also told me she doesn't see the $1.50 off ramp charge anywhere (missed toll/EZ Pass). What should I do to prevent a penalty for not paying the $1.50 off ramp charge?

Comment: "I knew I would have to pay the Dulles toll to drive to IAD" -> This isn't true. [The Dulles Access Road is free.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virginia_State_Route_267#Dulles_Access_Road)

Comment: @JacobHorbulyk True, but it was snowing and I thought the safest bet would be to take the faster way there from DC :)

Comment: It seems you've already contacted the most authoritative entity for this situation, which is EZ Pass. You could see if a different representative gives you a different answer, or try to escalate through their customer service.

Answer (score 3):

Dulles Toll Road is FREE if going to and from airport.
It is only toll (w/ 50-year-old coin payment devices) if exit early -- do not proceed all the way to the Airport.

A little hack (not worth the effort) = drive to airport, go around the circle for drop-off's and then return to the toll road and exit as wish .. doing this allows one to skip paying the exit fees.

Since YOU don't be getting off early, just drive to airport. Easy Peasy.

Worse case, go to airport like dropping off a relative/pal/colleauge.. and once pass the airport's front doors, keep going and look for signs for rental car rental lots.

Your rental car company can explain it to you. If you are renting from a tiny auto rental place, call one of the big ones (Hertz, Avis).

Comment: It's [illegal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/163800/cheating-the-dulles-access-road-how-do-the-police-know) to cheat the toll by backtracking through the airport if you don't have business there, and [the airport police will periodically enforce that](https://www.nbcwashington.com/news/local/police-crack-down-on-dulles-access-highway-backtracking/1931239/), though it's apparently acceptable if you buy something at the airport gas station or otherwise have business at the airport. But you're right the toll shouldn't apply to returning a rental car, which is airport business.